# MVC change image button image on the view from the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, button, controller

I am new to MVC .  I am creating a bookstore webpage application using aspx, and mvc.  I have a database of books that says available or sold out.  When a user clicks a dropdownlist they choose a book, it shows an image next to the book that is either supposed to show a green check mark if it is available or a red X if its not available.  That information is all pulled from a database.  My question is how do I change the image once a book becomes available.   By the way my images are stored in my Content folder under imgs.

I have been searching for a while and haven't found a good answer. Any help or any websites you can suggest would be great thanks.

My image says this

```
<asp:  Image ID = "Book_Availability" runat = "server" />
```

-----------Update----
When I mean change, I mean change the ImageURL so that it points to a different picture.  On the server side I have value of 0 or 1.  When I get a 1 i want to update the image URL to point to a different ImageURL from the controller, so that its from a X to a check mark. I am not sure how to accomplish this using MVC

Comment: What do you mean how do you change the image?  Wouldn't you just use if/then logic depending on the value of the database field?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link on [Razor syntax](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax).  You could achieve what describe with something like:

```
@{
    string availableImage = Url.Content("~/Images/availableImage");
    string unavailableImage = Url.Content("~/Images/unavailableImage");
}

<img  src= "@(Model.IsAvailable ? availableImage : unavailableImage)" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps add an click event handler onto the dropdown using jQuery.  This could in turn do a $("#myimagewrapperexample").load() event against an action on some controller i.e BooksController

The action could return a partial view containing the books current image for example.  Or it could return true, false depending on the books availability and you toggle the image in your javascript.  All the action would need to be passed would be the id of the book and you could then look it up to determine it's status.

I've never used asp tags in a MVC project so can't comment on your usage there.  AlexC suggestion of looking into the Razor syntax if your using MVC 3 is a good idea.  Otherwise you might want to look into creating views using MVC 2.  This [Microsoft link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410123.aspx) might help you out on that front.